# Can we Change the Values of ServerVariables?

Tags: .net, asp.net, variables

I want to change tha value of Request.ServerVariables["Remote_Addr"],is it Possible?
if yes please let me know how can we change?
if No  Please let me know why we can not change?

thanks in advance.

Comment: could you give some background to why you'd want to change Remote_Addr?

Comment: What would it mean to change the remote_addr anyhow? It's supposed to be what the client provided in the HTTP request. Why would it need to be changed?

Answer (score 0):

These can't be changed, as these are only readable, you can only get values and can't set.
Becoz ServerVariables collection is used to retrieve the server variable value.

Comment: -1 They can be changed by using reflection. http://forums.asp.net/t/1125149.aspx/1/10